# Decode and encode!

Tags: cipher

**Decode the question to encode the answer !**

> If triangle is encoded as rtusbhkr, then how would epidemic be encoded
>   ?

Try to think differently!

Comment: **Please check tag wikis before using any tags.** This is not ANY of the puzzle types you have tagged it as.

Comment: Oops sorry. thanks I'll correct it from next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be either:

> wqufwzuv or roosrnox

Depending on how you start.

> Just type the word on a qwerty keyboard alternating between the letter to the left or right of the letter you want to type. For triangle: T, left is R; R, right is T; I, left is U; etc.

Comment: I think the answer is the second one as the encoding for triangle seems to be avoiding wrapping around.

Answer (score 2):

The encoded answer is:

> w[ufw,uv

Explanation:

> Assuming you're using a standard *Engish Keyboard*
>
> For "triangle" => "rtusbhkr": On the keyboard, the letter 'R' is to the immediate left of 'T'. And the letter 'T' is to the right of 'R'. 'U' is to the left of 'I', and 'S' to the right of 'A', etc.
>  Follow the pattern alternating left/right and starting on the left.
>
> Applying this to "epidemic" will yield "w[ufw,uv".
> ('W' is left of 'E', '[' is right of 'P', etc.)
>
> **edit**: I did not consider wrapping around the keyboard to keep letters, clever.